# Identifying important features in forest model

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, fitting, boosting, importance

I want to identify important features with sklearn for a random forest model and now I am not sure to use the train dataset or the entire population dataset for identification?

The output from fitting my training dataset shows this:

[image]

Comment: The plot is showing you a score for each variable how important it is in predictions. Where is the issue?

Comment: Welcome to CV. This has little to do with random forests. Any model building should be done on the training set, lest you leak information from the test set.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, so it is sufficient when considering the training set and focusing on the three highest features?

Answer (score 0):

Toward's Data Science has great articles and tutorials for a lot of things. Here's a good resource for you to review: https://towardsdatascience.com/explaining-feature-importance-by-example-of-a-random-forest-d9166011959e

1. It's always best practice to use your training set when building out your models and whatnot.
2. If you have data with classes that only have 1 element of data per each class, then you can use the whole dataset instead of breaking it into training and test sets. This is because you could expect the trained network to be 100% accurate in its predictions and there would be no need to be concerned with issues such as bias and variance in the resulting model.
3. Read that article to its entirety because you have to pay attention to your data and what it's doing in order to correctly identify the best features.